# brackets used in C without control structures like if, loops

Tags: c, coding-style

What is the purpose of brackets `{}` in C code without the usage of
control structures like loops, if-else, function calls etc. ?

An example can be this:

```
    // Add UDP transport.
    {
        // Init transport config structure
        pjsua_transport_config cfg;
        pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.port = 5080;

        // Add TCP transport.
        status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
    }
```

Is this just to show that this is a way to split your code into semantic blocks during a long function? And if so, wouldn't it be cleaner to make this into an own function?

The code can be found in this blog:
[Xianwen's blog](http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/07/15/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-5/)

Comment: you are right, that partly answered my question. Thank you, I searched for a post like this, but found nothing. Now I still wonder if this seems to be a good style or not. In my oppinion it would be smarter to have subfunctions rather than cutting one large function into artificial scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the brackets you create a block of code. In the block, you can declare new variables. Those variables only have scope in the block and they cease to exist if the block is exited.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why would you do this instead of creating own functions for some parts?

Comment: There can be many reasons. Take for example a long switch statement (e.g. to process Windows messages), then it can be easier to quickly create some variables to handle the message than to create an own funcion.